# failover two redhat node

Tags: redhat, failover, failovercluster

I want to know is it possible to failover 2 Redhat physical nodes. both nodes are identical and they dont have any shared storage. I want to failover two separates redhat physical nodes when NodeA goes down all requests route to NodeB. I dont have any specific service like apache,nginx,mysql ,.... and therefore I cannot define resource like mysql,nginx,apache.... . is there any solution for routing all traffic on every ports to primary server and when it goes down all traffic route to secondary server?

I know UCARP can provide  failover based on IP for my servers but I want to know is there a better way to failover two nodes based on availability of OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat has documentation for this.

[CREATING A RED HAT HIGH-AVAILABILITY CLUSTER WITH PACEMAKER](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_administration/ch-startup-haaa)

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_administration/ch-startup-haaa

---

While you don't have a specific cluster-aware service, you can still define a virtual IP as a resource and have that shared between nodeA and nodeB.

Point your services to the floating virtual IP and use that as the failover service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to know is is possible to Failover based on availability of OS?

Comment: Yes, this is in the documentation

Comment: I  cannot find any information about OS availability on mentioned Documentation. Samba LVM HTTP and NFs is only available on documentation.

Comment: Be creative. Think about what Pacemaker is monitoring: the health and availability of a node.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your primary target is to setup HA for application server and db server if so, another option is with haproxy and keepalived please check this reference https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/load_balancer_administration/keepalived_install_example1 with same way you can do load balancing for nginx, mysql, apache and many more. Also haproxy gives you monitoring facility with stats and lots of other features.

Comment: No. I want to Setup HA based on OS availability. I dont have any specific service like DB , mysql , nginx and so on.